# How can I rewrite this Haskell using guards with no case-of?

Tags: haskell

I have three versions of a function laid out below. #2 and #3 work. #2 would be my first choice right now. I'd like to find some way of making #1 work, and see how it compares. It's down at the bottom.

First, I have this type:

```
data Value =
    IntVal Int
  | BoolVal Bool
  deriving (Show)
```

And this (working fragment of a) function:

```
-- #2
evaluate (If ec et ef) s0 =
  case vc of
    (IntVal ____) -> error "Conditional expression in If statement must be a boolean" 
    (BoolVal vcb) -> if vcb then (vt, st)
                            else (vf, sf)
  where (vc, sc) = evaluate ec s0
        (vt, st) = evaluate et sc
        (vf, sf) = evaluate ef sc
```

I'm wondering if I can get rid of the case statement and use guards instead. I can use guards *inside* the case statement, I've found this works:

```
-- #3
evaluate (If ec et ef) s0 =
  case vc of
    (IntVal _) -> error "Conditional expression in If statement must be a boolean" 
    (BoolVal vcb) | vcb       -> (vt, st)
                  | otherwise -> (vf, sf)
  where (vc, sc) = evaluate ec s0
        (vt, st) = evaluate et sc
        (vf, sf) = evaluate ef sc
```

That's good to know. I think #2 most clearly communicates my intentions. Nonetheless, here's the first thing I tried, and I'd like to figure out how it could actually work:

```
-- #1
evaluate (If ec et ef) s0 
  | (IntVal vc) = error "Conditional expression in If statement must be a boolean" 
  | vc == True  = (vt, st)
  | otherwise   = (vf, sf)
  where (vc, sc) = evaluate ec s0
        (vt, st) = evaluate et sc
        (vf, sf) = evaluate ef sc
```

Which gives the following errors. It seems like I need something that will ask if something of the Value type is also of the IntVal subtype?:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Value'
In the first argument of `IntVal', namely `vc'
In the expression: (IntVal vc)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `Value'
In the expression: (IntVal vc)
In a stmt of a pattern guard for
               an equation for `evaluate':
  (IntVal vc)
```

**How can I fix these errors and have a no-cases, guards-only implementation?**

Comment: As Ørjan Johansen showed, it's possible with PatternGuards – but IMO `case` is preferrable here, since what you're doing is simply match on alternatives. What's you _case_ against that solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your #1 is that ordinary guards can only be Boolean expressions, which have no power to succinctly match patterns.  So `IntVal vc` just won't work as one.  And even if it did, the `vc` you get from an `IntVal vc` pattern cannot be used as a `Bool` value - you need the `BoolVal vc` pattern for that.

However, you can use [pattern guards](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pattern_guard):

```
evaluate (If ec et ef) s0
  | IntVal _      <- vc = error "Conditional expression in If statement must be a boolean" 
  | BoolVal True  <- vc = (vt, st)
  | BoolVal False <- vc = (vf, sf)
  where (vc, sc) = evaluate ec s0
        (vt, st) = evaluate et sc
        (vf, sf) = evaluate ef sc
```

Comment: This is pretty neat. How I'm reading this is, for example, "If and only if `IntVal _` is coereced from `vc`, then error. If and only if `BoolVal True` is coerced from `vc`, then (vt,st). If and only if `BoolVal False` is coerced from `vc`, then (vf,sf)."

Comment: @AndrewK: that's pretty much correct, except that it's a pattern match, not a coercion.  It would be more accurate to say "If and only if `vc` matches `IntVal _`...", or perhaps "`vc` is of the form `IntVal _`".

Comment: While I think this approach reads the most fluidly, one issue I am noting is that the compiler has trouble following what patterns are and are not matched. E.g. it comes back with a warning for `Patterns not matched: (If _ _ _) _`. The `case` approach is more useful for ensuring the possibilities are exhausted.

Comment: Also, should anyone refer to this, you deal with the `accepting non-standard pattern guards (use PatternGuards to suppress this message)` warning by adding `{-# LANGUAGE PatternGuards #-}` pragma to the beginning of your file.

Comment: @AndrewK Ah right, I guess it doesn't do the necessary analysis for pattern guards yet.  Although you should be able to use the ordinary guard `| otherwise` in the last line, since you aren't using any matched variables in the right side.

Comment: @AndrewK pattern guards *are* standard since Haskell 2010, they should be available by default unless you are using a very old GHC version or explicitly choosing `Haskell98`.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't really an answer, but I'd write the whole thing something like this:

```
evaluate (If ec et ef) s0 =
    case evaluate ec s0 of
    (True,  sc) -> evaluate et sc
    (False, sc) -> evaluate ef sc
```

I find the naming of `vt`, `st`, `vf`, and `sf` to be harder to read because I have to trace the data flow of those variables myself.  Keeping them unnamed simplifies understanding.

Comment: Good call! As it happens, the code I wrote above is taken term-by-term from some operational semantics written in LaTex. When I'm home I'll take a look and see if working backwards from your implementation yields cleaner semantics. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you redefine the type `Value` using [record syntax](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax):

```
data Value = IntVal { unInt :: Int } | BoolVal { unBool :: Bool }
```

Then you can do:

```
evaluate (If ec et ef) s0 =
  if unBool vc then (vt, st) else (vf, sf)
  where (vc, sc) = evaluate ec s0
        (vt, st) = evaluate et sc
        (vf, sf) = evaluate ef sc
```

Comment: While I can follow this well enough to use it, I'm not really grokking how the compiler sees it. Is there a term for this `MyType { MySubtype1 :: MySubtype2 }` form that I can Google?

Comment: @AndrewK This is a so-called _record syntax_. You can read about it [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax).